# Add an image in background of a Histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to add an image to the background of a histogram. I am starting to use R and i had this idea from the last point of this guide on ggplot2: http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part2-Customizing-Theme-With-R-Code.html

This is the code i am using

```
library(ggplot2) 
**library(grid)
library(png)
img<- png::readPNG("logo.png")
g_pic<- rasterGrob(img,  interpolate=TRUE)**
ggplot(Ruta1600, aes(x=Ruta1600$fvec_aprox_md, fill=Ruta1600$nivel_dif_exp_codigo)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  labs(x="fvec_aprox_md", y="Count") +
  xlim(c(0,3000)) +
  facet_grid(Ruta1600$nivel_dif_exp_codigo~Ruta1600$fh_natural_id)    +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(Ruta1600$fvec_aprox_md)),color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  **annotation_custom(g_pic, xmin=5, xmax=7, ymin=30, ymax=45)**
```

And this the error i am getting:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(7L, 4L, 1L, 4L,  : 
  replacement has 415 rows, data has 1
```

I guess the problem is with the size of the image. I am still learning the basis of R, so excuse me if the answer to this question is too simple.

Thanks.

Comment: We can not use the code, because you didn't give us the data of your example. Is it possible to give us the data? Please use `dput(Ruta1600)` or if it is really big `dput(head(Ruta1600, 20))`. It is not necessary to use `$` to select the variables in `ggplot`. You can leave the `Ruta1600$` out!

Comment: the `cowplot` package has nice functions for annotating images on plots. See the [vignette here](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/drawing_with_on_plots.html)

Comment: @ricoderks thanks for the advice! Unfortunately i cannot share the data i am working with, but i guess if you could give me a simple example that would do it for me

Comment: @JanBoyer thank you very much! Cowplot seems to be pretty useful, i will try using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I couldn't use your data, I just used the `iris` data. I tried to use all the things you added to your plot. With the code below I don't get any error.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(png)

# location is relative to the work directory
img <- readPNG("./test/Rlogo.png")
g_pic <- rasterGrob(image = img,
                    interpolate = TRUE)

ggplot(data = iris,
       aes(x = Petal.Length,
           fill = Species)) +
  # place first, to make sure it is in the background
  annotation_custom(grob = g_pic,
                    xmin = 3,
                    xmax = 5,
                    ymin = 5,
                    ymax = 10) +
  # the histogram
  geom_histogram() +
  # the mean lines
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(Petal.Length)),
             color = "black", 
             linetype = "dashed", 
             size = 1) +
  # faceting
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

If for some reason part of the image is outside the plotting range use `expand_limits` to make the plotting range bigger.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is pretty useful for me!! Thanks for taking the time to answer it!